# reporting services add to table based on cell in the row

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

Here's my issue, I have a dataset with the results. I want to add rows to a tablix based on the column in the dataset called type (i.e. 1 tablix has rows where the type is "100 or less". The other table has rows added where the type is "100 or more")

How would I do this?

thank you,
Joel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways:

1. Use two datasets for the different tables and select the data you want there
2. Set the Visibility-Hidden property on the two tables to just show the data you want. For example, on the table to show "100 or less", click on the Detail row selector so entire row is selected. In the Properties panel, click the [+] icon on Visibility and type into the Hidden property the following expression:

   ```
   =Fields!Type.Value <> "100 or less"
   ```